# Proving a unique zero with the MVT

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$, and let $f(a)=0$ and $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. I need to show that $x=a$ is the only zero of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$.

How could I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there exists another point $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)=0$. Then there exists some point between $a$ and $c$ with derivative $0$.

Comment: hmmm, could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @PeejGerard, using MVT you get my conclusion, which contradicts to the assumption $f'(x)\neq0$.